# Custom fonts for password textfield placeholder ios

Tags: fonts, passwords, textfield, placeholder

I want to set custom fonts for password textfield ios. Thanks for hep.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:15.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.textColor}];
}
```

Comment: Could I set two different `fonts` to my placeholder?